# Flutter: How to reset SnackBar timer?

Tags: flutter, dart, snackbar

On a button tap I want to show a `SnackBar` for 5s.
If the user taps the button repeatedly in a short amount of time, multiple `SnackBar`s are queued.
Instead of showing e.g. 3 `SnackBar`s for 5s each, I want to reset the timer of the currently active `SnackBar` each time the button is tapped.
So if the user taps the button 3 times within 1s, I want to show one `SnackBar` for a total of 6s, instead of showing 3 `SnackBar`s for a total of 15s.

I do not know how to manipulate the timer of a currently active `SnackBar`. The `ScaffoldMessenger` only provides methods such as `removeCurrentSnackBar` to dismiss the `SnackBar` and not to manipulate the `SnackBar` in other ways, as far as I understood.

How can I achieve the reset of the Snackbar timer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple work around. Whenever the user clicks the button clear the snackbar and launch a new one. You can use `removeCurrentSnackBar` to remove.

Comment: This solution even convinced our designers :) Only one more line of code and it makes it quite obvious to the user that the snackbar is showing up because of his actions.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired behavior of resetting the timer of the currently active SnackBar, you can create a custom solution using Flutter's Timer class and a state management approach. Here's how you can do it:

Define a stateful widget:
Create a stateful widget that holds the state of the currently active SnackBar and manages the timer.

Use ScaffoldMessenger and SnackBar:
Wrap your main widget with a Scaffold and use ScaffoldMessenger to show and hide the SnackBar.

Create a custom SnackBar queue:
Maintain a queue to keep track of the tapped events and manage the SnackBar display time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This would have been the solution if our designers would have held on to their initial requirements, but the simplicity of @daikstrez's solution even convinced them to change the requirements :)